# Serilog doesn't parse file name templae

Tags: json, logging, serilog, serilog-sinks-file

I'm using serilog with this configuration:

```
{
    "Serilog": {
        "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
        "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
        "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId" ],
        "WriteTo": [
            { "Name": "Console" },
            {
                "Name": "File",
                "Args": {
                    "path": "./logs/performance-{Date}.log",
                    "rollingInterval": "Day",
                    "fileSizeLimitBytes": 1000,
                    "rollOnFileSizeLimit": true,
                    "retainedFileCountLimit": null,
                    "shared": true
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Output file should look like `20210613-performance.log` But output file looks like `{Date}-performance20210613.log`.

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `{Date}` placeholder is not a feature of the [`Serilog.Sinks.File`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file) sink that you're using. You're probably confusing with the (*deprecated*) [`Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-rollingfile) sink which has this feature.

With [`Serilog.Sinks.File`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file), at this time, you cannot define where the date will appear. It's always appended to the end of the file name you choose (and before the sequence number if you also are rolling by file size).

There have been [attempts](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file/issues/64) to implement this feature, but as of this writing it's not yet there.